# JavaScript: Cannot find the key in Map

Tags: javascript

I'll say right away that I'm new to javascript.

I cannot find the key in the Map. For example, I create an object of the Map class and add a key-value pair to it. Then I try to call the method has, but it returns false:

```
let dict = new Map()
dict["0"] = 0
console.log(dict.has("0")) // false
```

However, if I call the set method, then the method has will return true:

```
dict.set("1", 1)
console.log(dict.has("1")) // true
```

Who knows why I can't use the first option to add a key-value pair to the Map?

Comment: [Different ways for adding key/value pair to a Map in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52184618)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all fairly well explained by the [docs on `Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) but to put it simply, doing this

```
dict["0"] = 0
```

Sets the property on an object and does not interact with the Map's keys

> Setting Object properties works for Map objects as well, and can cause considerable confusion. [...] But that way of setting a property does not interact with the Map data structure. It uses the feature of the generic object